# Unable to make php curl request with port number

Tags: php, curl, port

I am unable to  make a php curl request with port number , without port number i am getting response properly.

Through terminal when i do  curl http://www.sample.com:8088  i am getting response back properly. But not through php curl on doing curl_inf()
 i am getting

```
Array ( [url] => http://www.sample.com:8088/ [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => 0 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [certinfo] => Array ( ) )
```

My code

```
$url = "http://www.sample.com:8088/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
$report=curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($report);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

this code give me response from ubuntu  , but not giving response from cent os if port number is specified.

Please let me know the how to fix it.

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to set the port like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
```

or:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to set

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);
```

See more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);
```

[Curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) reference

Comment: i tried with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);
 also but same result. I have also tried  by removing curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);

Answer (score 3):

"setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on" resolves the problem for me

Comment: Ok, but why? Please add some kind of explanation to your answer so that others know why this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the port 8080 is enabled in Cent OS

and try this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);`

Answer (score 0):

I went to server admin with this problem and he changed configuration in centos

in folder  /etc/sysconfig/

he edited file  selinux  and change  SELINUX=disabled and restated it.

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
```

and my problem got solved.

Comment: Disabling the entire SE Linux just to get curl to accept port numbers in the URL can't be a solution, a temp work-around at best but absolutely not something for the long run.

Comment: This should NOT be an accepted answer.  The answer by Mario should suffice.