# Can curl make a connection to any TCP ports, not just HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: php, curl

Can `curl` make a connection to any TCP ports not just HTTP/HTTPS

I need to check for an open port, for example: `11740`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, you will probably need to use the `CURLOPT_PORT` option, like so:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 11740);`

Bear in mind, you may face problems with SELinux:

[Unable to make php curl request with port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188988/unable-to-make-php-curl-request-with-port-number)

Answer (score 77):

Yes, it's possible, the syntax is `curl [protocol://]<host>[:port]`, for example:

```
curl example.com:1234
```

If you're using Bash, you can also use [pseudo-device `/dev` files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html) to open a TCP connection, e.g.:

```
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/1234
echo "send some stuff" >&5
cat <&5 # Receive some stuff.
```

<sup>See also: [More on Using Bash's Built-in /dev/tcp File (TCP/IP)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bashs-built-devtcp-file-tcpip).</sup>

Comment: also `curl -v telnet://example.com:1234`

Answer (score 20):

Of course:

```
curl http://example.com:11740
curl https://example.com:11740
```

Port 80 and 443 are just default port numbers.