# Failed to connect to host port 88: Conection Refused

Tags: php, curl

I`m trying to get a JSON information in a remote server with CURL but for some reason the server is refusing my connection.

I already tried many posts here, but with no success...

Return:
Failed to connect to host port 88: Connection Refused
Failed to get contents.

```
    $url = 'http://example.com:88/page.php';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
        echo "\n<br />";
        $response = '';
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    if (!is_string($response) || !strlen($response)) {
        echo "Failed to get contents.";
        $contents = '';
    }

    print_r($response);exit;
```

Is there any configuration on the remote server that might be blocking the connection?

I can open the URL and get all contents in my browser.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188988/unable-to-make-php-curl-request-with-port-number

Comment: I tried that as well... No success

Comment: Try providing a user agent and/or a referer.

Comment: Same result using agent and refere...

Comment: contact the host support