# Call an API with curl on a specific port

Tags: php, symfony, curl, fosrestbundle

I'm running my Symfony under the port 8000.
But curl HTTP is on port 80.

That means my curl request is not working because the port is not okay I think.

I tried to specify the port to curl. But doing this makes the call request failed... I have no error message, it's just like pending when I try to call it.

I have already checked this issue: [Unable to make php curl request with port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188988/unable-to-make-php-curl-request-with-port-number)

My $url is like `http://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php/api/someapi`

here `$result = $this->lib->CallAPI('POST', $url, $postfields);`

Running under Symfony to find the URL, I should have `127.0.0.1:8000`
But either I tried to set the port in the URL with not set curl option for the port. Either I try to use the URL without the port but setting the curl option for the port. It always failed.

Here is the function of making the call

```
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PORT, 8000);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

}

The line `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PORT, 8000);` seems to be responsible for making my request pending.

Note that the API call from Postman is working, so the issue is really on the way I call it with curl.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I used a little trick to see what is wrong.

instead of returning $result in callApi() I return the $curl. it returns me some HTML with inside this

```
<h1 class="break-long-words exception-message">Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>
<p class="break-long-words trace-message">An instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface must be injected in FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler to render templates.</p>
```

But I don't understand why defining the $curl variable make this error considering the called API is working on the postman

EDIT2 : In fact this erro rwas due to tryying to convert the curl object in json with json_decode...so nothing to do. Sorry. Issue still there then.

Comment: Can you not add the port into the URL string? E.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/api/someapi` You say things aren't working, but what are you getting back from these curl calls?

Comment: @JonStirling May be it was not clear, but using this callApi function, either I have the port in the url or not make the call pending. (It's pending, that means, I don't see anything on postman ... api 1 call api 2 with curl). api 2 is working but the curl failing make the api 1 pending...

Comment: Just a side note: stop using CUrl, start using `Guzzle` or other HTTP clients.

Comment: CURLOPT_PORT should have worked, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE, what is in stderr with CURLOPT_VERBOSE enabled?

Comment: @hanshenrik first message edited, looks like the issue is not directly related to curl.
DonCallisto: ok, I will consider this for later.