# Unable to make a api request having port number in php

Tags: php, curl, port, php-curl

I am unable to make a curl request to my restapi on localhost having port number like http://localhost:8082/create. My codes are in core php. Heres the code i have:

```
        $url = "localhost:8082/create";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8082);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$form_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I get curl error as couldnot connect to host.
Also i have tried @Mário Rodrigues solutions in this question [Unable to make php curl request with port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188988/unable-to-make-php-curl-request-with-port-number)
Is it not possible to call curl request having port number in it?
I have also tried using guzzle/httpclients, i got the same error as the curl error.

When i run `curl localhost:8082 -v` on terminal it gives:

```
curl localhost:8082 -v
*   Trying ::1:8082...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8082 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Date: Mon, 10 Jan 2022 05:09:40 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

But the php curl give cannot connect to host.

Comment: Make sure the outbound port 8082 is open and visible

Comment: The port is up, running and visible. Also the url can be browsed in browser.

Comment: Do you have a firewall that is preventing this, essentially, unknown app (curl) from accessing that port? Have you tried probing that port with [PortQry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/portqry-command-line-port-scanner-v2) or similar?

Comment: yes i tried with telnet and connection was successful. However on my code it shows couldnot connect to host.

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$response = curl_exec($ch); /* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show us the verbose log.

Comment: @hanshenrik  ```About to connect() to localhost port 8082 (#0) * Trying ::1... * Connection refused * Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connection refused * couldn't connect to host * Closing connection #0 ``` This was the output i got.

Comment: ok, you do not have a server listening on localhost port 8082. what do you get from `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`  ?

Comment: i do have port listening on 8082 when i run the above command i do get the result as 
```docker-pr  7682            root    4u  IPv4  93378      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  7688            root    4u  IPv6  92099      0t0  TCP *:8082 (LISTEN)```